# Remove variable labels attached with foreign/Hmisc SPSS import functions

Tags: class, r, import, label, spss

As usual, I got some SPSS file that I've imported into R with `spss.get` function from `Hmisc` package. I'm bothered with `labelled` class that `Hmisc::spss.get` adds to all variables in `data.frame`, hence want to remove it.

`labelled` class gives me headaches when I try to run `ggplot` or even when I want to do some menial analysis! One solution would be to remove `labelled` class from each variable in `data.frame`. How can I do that? Is that possible at all? If not, what are my other options?

I really want to bypass reediting variables "from scratch" with `as.data.frame(lapply(x, as.numeric))` and `as.character` where applicable... And I certainly don't want to run SPSS and remove labels manually (don't like SPSS, nor care to install it)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A belated note/warning regarding class membership in R objects. The correct method for identification of "labelled" is not to test for with an `is` function or equality {`==`) but rather with `inherits`. Methods that test for a specific location will not pick up cases where the order of existing classes are not the ones assumed.

You can avoid creating "labelled" variables in spss.get with the argument: , use.value.labels=FALSE.

```
w <- spss.get('/tmp/my.sav', use.value.labels=FALSE, datevars=c('birthdate','deathdate'))
```

The code from Bhattacharya could fail if the class of the labelled vector were simply "labelled" rather than c("labelled", "factor") in which case it should have been:

```
class(x[[i]]) <- NULL  # no error from assignment of empty vector
```

The error you report can be reproduced with this code:

```
> b <- 4:6
> label(b) <- 'B Label'
> str(b)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:3] 4 5 6
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "B Label"
> class(b) <- class(b)[-1]
Error in class(b) <- class(b)[-1] : 
  invalid replacement object to be a class string
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I get rid of the labels altogether. Similar to Jyotirmoy's solution but works for a vector as well as a data.frame. (Partial credits to Frank Harrell)

```
clear.labels <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)) {
    for(i in 1 : length(x)) class(x[[i]]) <- setdiff(class(x[[i]]), 'labelled') 
    for(i in 1 : length(x)) attr(x[[i]],"label") <- NULL
  }
  else {
    class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "labelled")
    attr(x, "label") <- NULL
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Use as follows:

```
my.unlabelled.df <- clear.labels(my.labelled.df)
```

**EDIT**

Here's a bit of a cleaner version of the function, same results:

```
clear.labels <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)) {
    for(i in seq_along(x)) {
      class(x[[i]]) <- setdiff(class(x[[i]]), 'labelled') 
      attr(x[[i]],"label") <- NULL
    } 
  } else {
    class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "labelled")
    attr(x, "label") <- NULL
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: I've ran your code and it worked for me. But I also have a question. The function `is.list` shows an output of `TRUE` when used a `data.frame` whose class is `tbl_df`, `tbl` and `data.frame`. Do you understand why the output shows this?

Comment: A `data.frame` is a list even though its class is not explicitly "list". Try `is(data.frame())`, and also `is(tibble::tibble())`; we could say that both df's and tibbles are "constrained" lists. They are generally rectangular (exception being that a df can contain a matrix, which is pretty odd), and if you look at the source code for `data.frame`, you'll see it's made from lists (e.g. `return(structure(list(), names = character(), row.names = row.names, class = "data.frame"))`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the `read.spss` function from the `foreign` package.

A rough and ready way to get rid of the `labelled` class created by `spss.get`

```
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    z<-class(x[[i]])
    if (z[[1]]=='labelled'){
       class(x[[i]])<-z[-1]
       attr(x[[i]],'label')<-NULL
    }
}
```

But can you please give an example where `labelled` causes problems?

If I have a variable `MAED` in a data frame `x` created by `spss.get`, I have:

```
> class(x$MAED)
[1] "labelled" "factor"  
> is.factor(x$MAED)
[1] TRUE
```

So well-written code that expects a factor (say) should not have any problems.

Comment: Actually, this approach doesn't remove the `labelled` class. Here's an error:
`Error in class(x[[i]]) <- z[-1] : 
  invalid replacement object to be a class string`

Comment: It worked with a SPSS file I tried. Can you please link to a sample file where this fails? Or give the output of

for (i in 1:ncol(x)) print(class(x[[i]]))

where x is the imported data frame.

Comment: Wouldn't you like to try `sapply(x, class)` instead of using loop? Oh, and, sadly, I can't recall which data file was I using... It was so long ago...

Comment: An example of this being important is a c("labelled", "factor") class object [breaking dplyr functions](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/658)

Comment: The code should use `inherits` and `setdiff` rather tthan the more fragile methods proposed above.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

```
library(Hmisc)
w <- spss.get('...')
```

You could remove the labels of a variable called "var1" by using:

```
attributes(w$var1)$label <- NULL
```

If you also want to remove the class "labbled", you could do:

```
class(w$var1) <- NULL
```

or if the variable has more than one class:

```
class(w$var1) <- class(w$var1)[-which(class(w$var1)=="labelled")]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out that `unclass` function can be utilized to remove classes (who would tell, aye?!):

```
library(Hmisc)
# let's presuppose that variable x is gathered through spss.get() function
# and that x is factor
> class(x)
[1] "labelled" "factor"
> foo <- unclass(x)
> class(foo)
[1] "integer"
```

It's not the luckiest solution, just imagine back-converting bunch of vectors... If anyone tops this, I'll check it as an answer...