# How to use utils::stack() with data labbeled with Hmisc in R

Tags: r

Playing around with R, I came across this really weird behavior of the `stack()` function :

```
library(Hmisc)
df = data_frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), col2=c(55,66,88,99,22,33))
stack(df) #works like a charm
label(df$col1)="column 1"
label(df$col2)="column 2"
stack(df) #Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector column selected
```

I guess this is caused by `class(df[1,1)=="numeric"` at first, but `class(df[1,1)=="labelled", "numeric"` at last.

Is there any clean workaround for this ?

Comment: I get error with `label(df$col1)="column 1"#
Error in label(df$col1) = "column 1" : could not find function "label<-"`

Comment: Ok nevermind, I switched base::labels and hmisc:label... noob error !

Answer (score 1):

I finally used Dominic Comtois's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070958/3888000) to get rid of labels :

```
stack(clear.labels(df)) #works fine
```